# Как найти английские фамилии в тексте?

Tags: python, pymorphy2

Есть список имён пользователей на английском языке. Как определить, что это имя и фамилия?
С pymorphy2, но она определяет только на русском языке. А как определить английские фамилии?

```
import pymorphy2

name_list = ['Василий', 'Екатерина', 'Супер', 'Aleksandra', 'Bybee', 'William']

for name in name_list:
    print(any('Name' in p.tag for p in morph.parse(name)))
```

```
True
True
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: На всякий случай, вот вам список известных людей с одинаковыми именами и фамилиями https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_reduplicated_names#American

Comment: В общем, ищите по словам `python nlp ner`, я сходу не нашёл простого варианта, там везде допиливать надо, похоже.

Answer (score 0):

```
a='noah aleksandra liam william mason james benjamin jacob michael elijah ethan emma bybee olivia ava sophia isabella mia charlotte abigail emily harper'.split()
b=['Василий', 'Екатерина', 'Супер', 'Aleksandra', 'Bybee', 'William']
for i in b:
    if i.lower() in a:
        f=True
    else:
        f=False
    print(f)
```

Расширяйте список `a`, чтобы Ваш код работал лучше и проверял больше имён
Кстати, добавьте в этот список также русские имена

Comment: а в питоне что, нельзя уже писать `f = i.lower() in a` вместо целого if?

Comment: Да, я знаю, просто понятнее человеку будет) а то попробуй пойми, когда всё напихано в одну строку